# JQGrid Inline editing of a row gets disabled in Jqgrid for the second time

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid

Inline editing of a row gets disabled in Jqgrid for the second time.
First time i click a row, edit the values and click enter.
Immediately i'm unable to edit the same row. Please help. My code:

Im unable to put my complete code here.

Comment: Your code? Where is your code?

Comment: You need to show code. If SO restrict you to post your full code, post it on Pastebin/git gist or similar services and post the link here.

Comment: <script src="https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d192e8f1978dd02e911370cd7a9627fa.js"></script>

Comment: I have created the gist as u suggested and please find the link in my previous comment.